# Delay in the effect of addClass on Body when using iOS

Tags: jquery, css, ios, angularjs

Within an AngularJS controller using any of these:

```
        $('body').addClass('whiteBG');
        ('body').attr('style','background-color: white !important');
        body.classList.add('whiteBG');
```

The body elements background color does not change until some scrolling happens and then there is a bit of a delay till the background colour changes. Other effects of adding the 'whiteBG' class such as font color happen immediately. Is there a way to force some sort of refresh to fix this?